# ApiCurio: How to edit/update the whole API definition object?

Tags: javascript, typescript, frontend

I want to modify ApiCurio Studio source code (front end code) in order to add a feature: to modify/transform the Api before downloading.

So how could we do that?

After going through the source code and as far as I understand, I guess we need to open an editing session. Then update the API, then close the session. But I am not sure how we could do that exactly. Do we need an `ICommand` so we could update the API?

Thanks a lot.